# converted visual hello world python

Tags: python, pyside6

I have a directory/folder containing two files,
MainWindow.py
Mainwindow.ui

I have designed my MainWindow.ui in QtDesigner6   and  converteded
the output file  to MainWindow.ui

I have a code window that launches a window/form and is displayed
in it's full glory a blank window that is shown and can be closed.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()

window.show()  

app.exec_()
```

**This code I have grabbed from a book, my question is how to get this code
to launch my converted MainWindow.ui file instead of just a blank window?**

I have tried changing the line to:window = MainWindow()
thus deleting the QWidget and other permitations but not showing my nicly crafted ui

Comment: You may want to convert `.ui` file to `.py` file and then you can use it the same way you use other python classes or you can use  `QUiLoader` to load ui file into the python program. You may want to take a look at [PyQt/PySide: How to use .ui files?](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form file is not used in your application automatically, you have to manually load the
file and create the window based on it using `QUiLoader`. In your example, this would be something like:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

main_form = QFile("MainWindow.ui")
main_form.open(QFile.ReadOnly)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QUiLoader().load(main_form)
window.show()  

app.exec_()
```

Another option would be using the `pyside6-uic` tool to generate a class for a widget based on your form file:

```
$ pyside6-uic MainWindow.ui > main_window.py
```

Then use it in your code like:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from main_window import UI_MainWindow # your form class name with a UI_ prefix

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QMainWindow()
UI_MainWindow().setupUi(window)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```